# How to create specific size message to send via UDP socket in C++?

Tags: c++, integer, udp

I'm trying to write a small application that will "concatenate" a bunch of integer variables of various sizes (uint8, uint16, uint32) into a 128 byte message that will be sent via UDP socket.

On the receiving side, I would like to split the message back into the individual integers and store them for further processing. For now I am assuming that endianness will not be an issue.

Could I get some hints on how to concatenate the int variables and later extract them from that 128 byte message?

Comment: `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::array<unsigned char,128>` - to copy the integers in or out just use memcpy.

Comment: Does your "bunch of integer variables" actually represents some fixed data structure? If so, it would be much easier to create a `struct` or `class` and send it's contents via udp

Comment: @DenisSheremet I am trying to simulate an actual piece of hardware which sends the integers in a 128 byte message. I do know the sizes and addresses for all the ints within the message. I won't be able to change the way hardware sends the data, and also I don't have the actual hardware yet, therefore the need to simulate it.

Comment: This is a case for `writev()` and `readv()`, or `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()`.

Comment: @user207421 wouldn't it be more overhead telling those methods where to get data from?  I thought they were mostly designed for the case when the buffers are significantly larger than the size of an `iovec`

Comment: @SamMason More overhead than what? Why? All the data has to be transferred from user space to the kernel and back anyway, and the solutions that involve further copying in the user space just add more copy steps. It should be *less* overhead.

Comment: @user207421 e.g. assuming OP individually scatters 64 * u16s then that's 1KB of `iovec`s (i.e. 64*16 bytes) telling the kernel what to do.  userspace still needs to set up all those iovecs which seems like more work that just unpacking those 128 bytes directly.  of course this varies depending on what is being requested, but (given the question) suggesting those APIs seems like overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's say you expect to recieve data in the following order:

`int32_t header; int8_t opcode; int16_t args[32]; int32_t clients[2]; ...`

This is just an example, parameters could be whatever they are in your actuai task.

You can wrap those parameters into `struct` or `class`. I'd prefer a `struct` here because it does not seem like you really need to create a ctor, access specifiers or any other fancy stuff `class` can provide. So, something like that:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct DataFromMyHardware {
    int32_t header;
    int8_t opcode;
    int16_t args[32];
    int32_t clients[2];
    ...

};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

`pragma`s here used to tell compiler to not optimize placement or alignment of variables in struct, so it'll be stored in memory as is.

This way, you can use this on sender:

```
DataFromMyHardware buffer;
buffer.header = 0xDEADBEEF;
buffer.opcode = 42;
...
send(socket, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

and on reciever:

```
DataFromMyHardware buffer;
recv(socket, (void*)&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

Side note: it's very likely that your device uses network byte-order, so you probably want to use `nhohl/ntohs` on reciever and `htonl/htons` on sender.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a character buffer prefix that will precede each integer which will define which type of integer to read so then you can read the correct size of the integer that is defined.

for ex:  Precede each integer with a character representing the integer.  The first byte will contain the character which you will interpret as an, it could be any ascii character that will represent the integer.

array ==  [byte][byte-8bit][byte][2 byte-16bit][byte][4 byte -32bit]...

UINT8 = 'a'
UINT16 = 'b'
UINT32 = 'c'  or whatever code you want the ascii to be...  I used a,b,c so its a readable character you can read in the debugger

You will then have to build your array to be sent with the prefix so you know what size to do your next read.

array = [a0b00c0000a0b00c0000]  and so on, you can build the array using memcpy

You can then send the whole packet of 128 bytes

Make sure you read exactly 128 bytes, and then you can deconstruct, remember that when you read you have to check the amount that was read from the socket, and continue to read until you receive the correct amount.  -- sometimes a read will not return the correct amount of bytes that you will expect.

When you receive the packet, you can deconstruct the packet using the headers, and depending on the header that you receive you can remove the correct integer and size, and the headers with the correct size should be deconstructed rather easily.

Also remember that UDP is lossy so you will possibly lose packets

Now also remember that if your constructed packet does not equal exactly 128 bytes every time you will need to add another byte which will be equivalent to a integer which will tell you exactly how many bytes were sent... 122..126..127 etc, and read that as the first header on the other side.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Unfortunately I can't add any characters to the UDP message. This is because I am trying to simulate an actual piece of hardware which sends 128 byte message, which contains the integers. I do however know the exact size and address for each int in the message.

Comment: You could use memcpy to concatenate each integer into the buffer if you know the exact ordering.  memcpy(buffer, &int8bit, sizeof(int8bit); memcpy(buffer[sizeof(int8bit)+1], &int16bit, sizeof(int16bit));   ... and so on until your buffer is full, and retrieve the data the same way just copying out of the buffer.